# Can't cast a value from a subclass Swift

Tags: swift, class, casting

I made a lot of research but I didn't find an answer to my question. Others talk about basic issues with Swift classes. Still I have an issue with my own classes. I also read courses about classes but it didn't help me.

I have two classes; one of them inherit from the other.

Here is my classes code :

```
class GlobalUser {

    var uid: String!
    var publicName: String!
    var pushID: String!
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!
    var example1: [String:String]!

    var fullName: String! {
        get {
            return firstName + " " + lastName
        }
    }

    init(document: DocumentSnapshot) {

        guard let data = document.data() else {
            print("Missing user information during initialization.")
            return
        }

        self.uid = document.documentID
        self.publicName = (data["publicName"] as? String)!
        self.pushID = (data["pushID"] as? String)!
        self.example1 = (data["example1"] as? [String : String])!

        let name = data["name"] as? [String:String]
        self.firstName = (name!["firstName"])!
        self.lastName = (name!["lastName"])!
    }

}

class InterestingUser: GlobalUser {

    var code: Int?
    var example: [String:String]?

    var number: Int! {
        get {
            return example.count
        }
    }

    override init(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        super.init(document: document)
    }
}
```

And then I try to cast a `GlobalUser` to a `InterestingUser` like this :

```
if let interestingUser = user as? InterestingUser {
...
}
```

But this cast always fails...

Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is `user`? Show code where you declare and initialize `user`.

Comment: Analogy. All Squares are Rectangles, but not all Rectangles are Squares. If you create a rectangle object that isn't square you can't cast it to a square because it ISN'T a square.

Comment: Sandeep. Sorry I failed: I wanted to rename the properties to remove some confusion but I failed by renaming 2 different properties with the same name "example". Edited.

Comment: rmaddy. regardless of the user definition, As Duncan C and digitalHound explained, I was confused with inheritance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're experiencing is due to this statement from your question: '*And then I try to cast a GlobalUser to a InterestingUser like this...*' and is due to inheritance.

Your `GlobalUser` class is the superclass. Your `InterestingUser` is a subclass of your `GlobalUser`.

So your `InterestingUser` class 'knows' about the `GlobalUser` because it is it's parent and you can cast `InterestingUser as? GlobalUser` but not the other way around.

Example:

```
if let interstingUser = InterestingUser() as? GlobalUser {
    // this will succeed because InterestingUser inherits from GlobalUser
}

if let globalUser = GlobalUser() as? InterestingUser {
    // this will fail because GlobalUser is not a subclass of InterestingUser
}
```

Here's some playground code for you to test with:

```
class GlobalUser {

}

class InterestingUser: GlobalUser {

}

class Demo {
    func comparison() {
        let interesting = InterestingUser()
        let global = GlobalUser()

        if let intere = interesting as? GlobalUser {
            print("Interesting is global as well")
        }
        if let global = global as? InterestingUser {
            print("Global is interesting")
        }
    }
}

let demo = Demo()
demo.comparison()
// prints 'Interesting is global as well'
```

Comment: Nice answer. Well explained. Thanks a lot !